# Setting the text of TextView that fits the screen Height and Width independently of the text size of TextView

Tags: android

I have a very large string that wont fit in the screen if I shown it as a TextView. Could any one tell me how to select a sub string which exactly fit the screen Height and Width independently of the text size of TextView.

Answer (score 0):

add these attribute to your TextView in the xml

```
   android:singleLine="true"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: Hi Javanator, you misunderstood my question, I am not looking for a single line TextView, I want a TestView that fits the entire screen. I am looking for the exact number of characters for that.

Comment: If view is larger then the screen size and text size is not be compromized then put the textview in a scroll view with fill_parent height and width

Comment: Hi Javanator, thank you for your comment. I am trying to develop an epub reader. I want to show the TextView in two pages if the text not fit in the current screen. For that I need the exact number of characters that fits the screen.

Comment: This totaly depends over the text font size. you calculate the the toatl width of avialable screen Using Display and WindowManager classes and then calculate the number of character that will fit into one line, and thus similarly calculate the number of lines in the screen..

Comment: Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

  int width = display.getWidth();
         int height = display.getHeight();

Comment: we can make simple function for this that will simply receive TextView and String Reference and will automatically makes it substring fitting into main display screen..